# jQuery infinite scroll pagination but in scroller hit top bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

I have found many plugins that enables pagination while scroll bottom and the one of code is like below using scrollpagination().

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#content').scrollPagination({
    'contentPage': 'democontent.html',
    'contentData': {}, 
    'scrollTarget': $(window),
    'heightOffset': 0, 
    'beforeLoad': function(){ 
        $('#loading').fadeIn(); 
    },
    'afterLoad': function(elementsLoaded){
         $('#loading').fadeOut();
         var i = 0;
         $(elementsLoaded).fadeInWithDelay();
         if ($('#content').children().size() > 100){ 
            $('#nomoreresults').fadeIn();
            $('#content').stopScrollPagination();
         }
    }
});

// code for fade in element by element
$.fn.fadeInWithDelay = function(){
    var delay = 0;
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).delay(delay).animate({opacity:1}, 200);
        delay += 100;
    });
};

});
</script>
```

I haven't found any idea to detach the scroll up function. I am trying to make a chat application which displays history, But right now I am trying to load all the chat history . Can any body help me to detach scroll top in above code.

Please Help me in this thing.